# GeoXML3 is not defined and cannot view data from KML file on own server?

Tags: javascript, maps

I have tried to follow the following example at, https://gist.github.com/webapprentice/8427539, which when ever I try to display their KML from an external link I am able to display the polygon correctly, however if I copy and past the KML into a file and place this file on my server I am not able to display the results for the KML file. This is true of any third party KML file. Interestingly, I've noted that the coordinate values are inverse, but whenever I switch these values using http://kmltools.appspot.com/geoconv the KML file still does not function properly. I assume that the KML information is valid, because when I enter the contents into the text box at http://display-kml.appspot.com/ the map to left displays my polygons correctly.

In order to find a solution, I have added geoxmlv3.js to my server and am trying to parse the KML file into a format that my maps can understand as I assume that my server is not able to render the KML file properly. You can view the results of the KML file below under the HTML & JavaScript. GeoXML gives me two errorrs: `Missing catch or finally after try` and `geoXML3 is not defined`. These errors do not make much sense to me as I have already decleared the file above in my code which you can see below.

In addition, I have had a mime type added to IIS where file extention is kml and type is application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml. I believe that this mime type works because when the page is directed to the file, the file is downloaded as does any other third party KML file.

========= HTML & JavaScript ==========

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyAjC_rKyBOaIBHtTu39GjC8h4SFWxry-s4"></script>
 <script src="/js/geoxmlv3.js"></script>
<script>
  var map;
  var mylocation = {
     'latitude':  47.66,
'longitude': -122.355
  }

   function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( mylocation.latitude,     mylocation.longitude );
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map}); 
    myParser.parse('/zoneManagers.kml'); 


// This needs to be the Full URL - not a relative URL
// var kmlPath = "zoneManagers.kml";
// // Add unique number to this url - as with images - to avoid caching issues during development
// var urlSuffix = (new Date).getTime().toString();
// var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlPath + '?' + urlSuffix );
//layer.setMap(map);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



</script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

===== KML File =====

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4v8eru0o3zp8xq/zoneManagers.kml?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About not being able to display the results of the KML file when you host it on your server. What server are you talking about ? Are you talking about a dev server running for example on localhost, a server in your local LAN or a public server accessible by anyone? 
Are you using a fully-qualified URL for the KML like in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/webapprentice/8427539) `http://web-apprentice-demo.craic.com/assets/maps/fremont.kml` ? Can the URL you're specifying be copy/pasted in any browser to access the file without any restrictions?

Google need to be able to access the KML file to process it and it's using the URL you're specifying to access it. If you're running on localhost, a private server or not specifying a public fully-qualified URL, Google can't access it.

If you're not doing that, you need to place the KML file on a public available domain and specify a fully-qualified public URL.

This option is not always possible if you're dealing with sensitive information, so your idea to use [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) is the best option.

I have no problem running the code you provided and to successfully display the map & the KML file.

Since `geoXML3 is not defined`, I think it's possible you're not importing the file correctly.

- Is your `geoxmlv3.js` in a `js` folder ?
- Are you importing the correct file ? ([source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/kmz/geoxml3.js))
- Did you rename the official file named `geoxml3.js` to `geoxmlv3.js` since you're trying to import `/js/geoxmlv3.js` and not `/js/geoxml3.js` ?
- Is the `js` folder at the root of your server ? You may need to use `js/geoxml3.js` instead without the first `/`.

You can also check in your browser inspector (Network tab) that `geoxmlv3.js` is correctly loaded.

[image: Inspector]

The 200 status code indicates that the `geoxmlv3.js` is correctly loaded.